# ADFS configuration fails with 'The server is unwilling to process the request'

Tags: windows-server-2016, adfs

I am trying to configure ADFS on Windows Server 2016. I followed a bunch of guides online and managed to setup the Directory Service, and Certificate Service. When I try to finish post-deployment configuration for ADFS, the setup fails with the following error.

> The specified service account 'CN=' did not exist. Attempt to create the group Managed Service Account failed. Error: The server is unwilling to process the request.

There is a warning about the root key being setup less than 10 hours ago (5 at the time of writing). Does this mean I have to wait another 5 hours before I can finish configuring ADFS? Or is there anyway I can recreate the root key?

PS - This is a single server with a single domain.

Comment: did you find a solution?